# Starting embedded servers before context loads in Spring Boot for testing

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am working on a [sample application](https://bitbucket.org/codechimp/beer-demo-spring-boot/src/master/) right now using Spring Boot, Spring Data JPA, and Spring Data Elasticsearch.  I want to be able to run the unit tests as part of a pipeline build, but they require Elasticsearch to be running to work as the service makes calls to said ES server.  SQL works fine because I am using an in-memory H2 instance.

I have implemented some code to attempt to launch ES as an "embedded" server.  The embedded server works just fine, but it seems like, at least from what I can tell, it is started AFTER the context loads.  Most importantly after the `ElasticSearchConfiguration` does it's thing.

I think I need refactor the code out of AbstractElasticsearchTest into a separate class that can run prior to `ElasticSearchConfiguration` generates the client/template, but I am not sure how to do it, nor how to Google said process.

Is there some mechanism in Spring Boot that could be used to start the embedded servers prior to running any of the configurations?  Or is there some way I could enhance `ElasticSearchConfiguration` to do it prior to creating the client/template, but only when running the unit tests?

**Edit:**
So, just to be a little more specific...what I am looking for is a means/way to either run ES 5 in "embedded" mode OR how to mock up the Spring Data ES code enough so that it works for the CI server.  The code linked above currently is mixing unit tests with integration tests, I know, as it's currently making calls to a physical ES server.  That's what I am trying to correct: I should be able to stub/mock enough of the underlying Spring Data code to make the unit test think it's talking to the real-deal.  I can then change the tests that determine if the documents made it to ES and test things like type-ahead searches to be integration tests instead so they do not run when CI or Sonar runs.

Comment: Are you doing integration test? Do you really need Elastic Search up in test cases?

Comment: If there is a way to mock the ES portion then I am ok with doing that.  I am storing the ES document when I store the Hibernate entity, so if it's stubbed/mocked I don't care

Comment: There's a testing framework for Elasticsearch with which you can run an embedded ES node for your tests. See here: (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/testing-framework.html). If you want to mock instead, then you should mock your facade used to access ES. If you don't have that, then I think you'll have to mock the ES client.

Comment: @Quagaar, thanks!  I think this looks just like what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so for those that might come back here in the future, [this commit](https://bitbucket.org/codechimp/beer-demo-spring-boot/commits/b96d26bdf03af5494e1446d63c8e26d568fbb719) shows the changes I made to get ES to run as "embedded".

The nuts-and-bolts of it was to start the node as "local" then physically return `node.client()`.  Then in the Spring Bean method that gets the client, check if you have "embedded" turned on, if so start the node and return it's Client (the local one), if not just build the client just as normal.